# Horizontal spacing in fraction

Tags: spacing, fractions

Followed is a small fraction code. As you can see, the spacing around "+" is too small. We can add `\:` or `\;` around "+" to increase the spacing. But, if the equation is complex, adding `\:` for where it needs is annoying. Can we adjust the spacings easily?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}
$\mathsf{\upxi_{x}=\frac{\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^2+1+\upeta_{x}}{2\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^2}=\frac{(\frac{87.1}{90})^2+1+0.240}{2\bigl(\frac{87.1}{90}\bigr)^2}=}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit 1:
Using `\dfrac` looks better. We need the package `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{upgreek,amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathsf{\upxi_{x}=\dfrac{\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^2+1+\upeta_{x}}{2\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^2}=\dfrac{(\frac{87.1}{90})^2+1+0.240}{2\bigl(\frac{87.1}{90}\bigr)^2}=}$
\end{document}
```

[image: better looking fraction]

Answer (score 1):

Given the complexity of the fraction expression, you may want to typeset it in display-style math mode instead of if inline or text-style math mode. In the following screenshot, the first row employs text-style math mode (as you do in the screenshot you posted), while the second row employs shows the same material in displaymath style.

If a `\frac` expression is encountered while TeX is in `\displaystyle` mode, the numerator and denominator terms are each typeset in `\textstyle` mode, with whitespace inserted between objects of type `math-ord` and `math-bin`, respectively. In contrast, if a `\frac` expression is encountered while TeX is in `\textstyle` mode, the numerator and denominator terms are each typeset in `\scriptstyle` mode. As you have (re)discovered, TeX is programmed to typeset scriptstyle (and scriptscriptstyle) material compactly, i.e., without whitespace around binary and relational operators.

[image]

For this screenshot shows, I've deleted the `\bigl` and `\bigr` sizing directives in the `\frac` that's processed in inline math mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{upgreek,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{\upxi_{x}}
&=\textstyle
  \mathsf{\frac{(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90})^2+1+\upeta_{x}}{%
  2(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90})^2}
=\frac{(\frac{87.1}{90})^2+1+0.240}{%
  2(\frac{87.1}{90})^2}=\cdots}
\tag*{\ttfamily\string\textstyle}\\[2ex]
&=\mathsf{\frac{\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}+1+\upeta_{x}}{%
  2\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}}
=\frac{\bigl(\frac{87.1}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}+1+0.240}{%
  2\bigl(\frac{87.1}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}}=\cdots}
\tag*{\ttfamily\string\displaystyle}
\end{align*}

\medskip
As a standalone displaymath object:
\[ % <- initiate a display math group
\mathsf{\upxi_{x}
=\frac{\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}+1+\upeta_{x}}{%
 2\bigl(\frac{\uplambda_{x}}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}}
=\frac{\bigl(\frac{87.1}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}+1+0.240}{%
 2\bigl(\frac{87.1}{90}\bigr)^{\!2}}=\cdots}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am producing calculation sheet. It consists of several columns. The equation shown above is in the main column, which is required to be left aligned. Using `\displaystyle` makes it centred in default.

Comment: @warem - I can think of (at least) two ways to change the alignment of displayed equations from centered to flush-left (aka ragged-right). (a) Instead of writing `\[ <stuff> \]`, write `$\displaystyle <stuff>$`. (b) Load the `amsmath` package with the option `fleqn` (short for "flush-left equations", I suppose) and issue the instruction `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` in the preamble.

Comment: I didn't try the option `amsmath`. But, `$\displaystyle <stuff>$` does work. Wonderful!